# Which component to install to get VC folder inside Windows Docker container?

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-2019, windows-container

I am getting below error when i try to build and run c++ program.

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

so i have checked inside this specific folder and i am missing v160 folder.

Question :- how can i install or put this folder in windows container?[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYTSF.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you @user7860670  link which you have commented i already checked earlier, but be more specific regarding msbuild , for instance  "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools " will add azure tool in docker what is command for msbuild?

Comment: There is a link to the Visual Studio Build Tools component list there.

Comment: Thanks @user7860670 that was helpful but none of component has installed buildtool VC/v160 in directory. Do you know how can i get this specifc dir?thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to know the same - the exact workload that will get the cpp items in the v160 directory. Anyone had luck with this?

Comment: @AmmarArnt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551660/add-or-copy-folder-to-windows-docker-container you can see this which might be helpful for you.