# Add or copy folder to windows docker container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, windows-container

I want to copy a folder to a windows container specific directory. I am not able to add it.

I tried

```
ADD VC  C:\TEMP\VC
```

This works and put my VC folder into windows container folder `C:\TEMP\VC`.

But when I try:

```
ADD VC  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\buildtools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC
```

I get the error:

```
Step 4/6 : ADD VC  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\buildtools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC
ADD failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder462071631\Program: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have also tried:

```
ADD VC  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\buildtools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC"
failed to process "\"C:\\Program": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote

Step 4/6 : ADD VC  C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\buildtools\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VC
ADD failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder633588211\Program: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Nothing works.

Dokcerfile

```
# escape=`

# Use the latest Windows Server Core image with .NET Framework 4.8.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe
ADD VC  C:\TEMP\VC   
#ADD /ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe   C:\
# Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.Component.MSBuild `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WinXP`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.20.x86.x64 `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.MSM`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.14.25.CLI.Support`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler`
    -add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.VisualStudioExtensionBuildTools.Prerequisites`
    -add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VSSDKBuildTools`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended \ `
     --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreBuildTools \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.Desktop \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP.Native \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Win81 \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest \`
    --add Microsoft.Component.VC.Runtime.UCRTSDK \`
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WinXP \`
    --add Microsoft.Component.MSBuild `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 `
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

# Define the entry point for the docker container.
# This entry point starts the developer command prompt and launches the PowerShell shell.
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&","powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Comment: can you share the content of DockerFile/docker-compose?

Comment: @Hamid Sure. i have attached snippet of dockerfile.

Comment: COPY ["path", "c:\path with spaces\"] should work

Comment: Step 4/7 : COPY ["C:\BuildTools\VC","C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\buildtools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC"]
failed to process "[\"C:\\BuildTools\\VC\",\"C:\\Program": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching double-quote

Comment: @CodedBeard it's not working

Comment: Try switching the slashes, I've just tried this and it worked fine: COPY ["Test.txt", "c:/Program Files (x86)/"]

Comment: @CodedBeard for specific file COPY works, i want to copy folder. it doesn't work

Comment: That command also works fine with folders as long as you are specifying the path correctly. COPY ["testfolder", "c:/Program Files (x86)/testfolder/"] copys a folder called testfolder which exists in the root of the build directory to c:\Program Files (x86)\testfolder along with all its contents in the container.

Comment: @CodedBeard i am still getting error  COPY ["VC", ""C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/buildtools/MSBuild/Microsoft/"]
failed to process "Studio/2019/buildtools/MSBuild/Microsoft/\"]": unexpected end of statement while looking for matching

Comment: Does that folder actually exist in the container? The copy command will only create the last part of the path. I've just had a look in the default image and it doesn't have that folder.

Comment: you mean VC .till MIcrosoft it's exist. VC is not that's why i want to add this folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
COPY ["VC", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VC"]
```

With the build directory as follows

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          16/07/2020    12:34                VC
-a---          16/07/2020    14:36            174 Dockerfile
```

Running a docker build will copy the contents of the VC folder in the build root, to the VC folder at the target without error

```
C:\temp\test> docker build -t testcopy .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
 ---> be6035551084
Step 2/2 : COPY ["VC", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VC"]
 ---> 7521a3e989ce
Successfully built 7521a3e989ce
Successfully tagged testcopy:latest
```

If you then run the created container, you should find the files are correctly copied

```
C:\>dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VC"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B40D-C55F

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC

07/16/2020  02:37 PM    <DIR>          .
07/16/2020  02:37 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/16/2020  12:26 PM                 0 Test.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  21,206,806,528 bytes free
```

If you are still getting errors, you may have a dodgy install of docker. This test was run with the lastest docker desktop version on server 2019 and the copy worked fine.