# is it possible to run already built container instead of creating built?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, window

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   NAMES                                       
487496bf2a3b        buildtools2019      "C:\\Program Files (x…"   trusting_hertz
```

I already have buildtools2019 container. Now i want to run visual-studio project in this container. How can i do it.I tried below one command but it's building new container.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -v C:\BuildTools\ConsoleApplication2:C:\ConsoleApplication2 --name CP5 buildtools2019 msbuild C:\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln -maxcpucount:3 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64
```

Comment: Why is running a new container bad?

Comment: Becuases of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551660/add-directory-to-windows-container